# Yocto: Adding Kernel Module to Image

Tags: kernel-module, yocto

I added `iptables` package to my device image, using `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "iptables"`.

I tried to run it on the device and get the following error message:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.11-1.0.0+gc27010d
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Seems like I have missing kernel module.

Need your help in adding standard kernel module to the image (Where can I find all modules files and how should I add and load it to the image).

Comment: You need to activation iptables in your kernel, and the way it is done depends on your kernel version.

Comment: Kernel version is 4.9.11-1.0.0. What's next?

Comment: In Yocto, you have one type of kernel that allows [configuration fragments](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-config-fragments) and one type that doesn't, and you have to replace the entire [defconfig](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#changing-the-configuration). In every cases, you can configure your kernel with `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel` and check in network that netfilter/iptables option is set.

Comment: Thank you. I used `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`, but I could not find the module that contains `iptables`. Do you have any idea where it might be found?

Comment: iptables kernel side is called netfilter, see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/netfilter/Kconfig for example. You can search for options with '/' in console menu.

Answer (score 8):

You must add the `iptables` module to your kernel. I had the same problem and I could solve it with these steps:

- Run `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`
- Activate `CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES` module (you can search its location on that menu typing slash '/').
- Save it and run `bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel` for saving that file as a defconfig.
- Copy `defconfig` file from returned path to `yocto-distro/layer-name/recipes-kernel/linux/files/` (make this directory if it does not exist).
- Create a `.bbappend` file inside `yocto-distro/layer-name/recipes-kernel/linux/` with the same name as your original recipe file from `meta` layer.
- Edit your file and append lines below:

```
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
KERNEL_DEFCONFIG = "${WORKDIR}/defconfig"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files"
~
```

- Relaunch `bitbake your-image-name`

---

It worked on my situation. Btw, I got that info from the following webs:

- http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Customizing_the_Linux_kernel
- https://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x651.html

Have a nice day! :D